# Adding additional data on an existing child in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database structure:

```
[Database Name]
     Users
       - Maria
       - Jane
```

How can I add new data under the Users Table? I have tried set but it turns out it overwrites all the data inside.

Answer (score 1):

Use the update method instead:

```
admin.database().ref(`users/${userid}`).update({data:1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as [d.mares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3875046/d-mares), here's how you can do it using .update()

Either

```
firebase.database().ref('Users').update({
    Foo: {name: 'foo', age: 'bar'}
})
```

Or

```
firebase.database().ref(`Users/${Foo}`).update({
    name: 'foo',
    age: 'bar'
})
```